# Executar aplicação em segundo plano

Tags: vb.net

Tenho uma aplicação desenvolvida em VB.NET que tem várias rotinas que são iniciadas com um timer. Está disponível na aplicação de console. O usuário não faz a interação ao console.

O que é a aplicação é executado em segundo plano. Na verdade já tenho um serviço sem janelas que iniciam uma aplicação, mas ela é um executivo do código e "para" mas se eu executar dando dois cliques, funciona perfeitamente.

Como posso fazer com que minha aplicação seja executada em segundo plano sendo que ja tem um serviço executando uma aplicação?